# django specific url/view that wont modify the session expiry date?

Tags: django, session, session-timeout

As I see each time the session is changed, i.e `request.session['last_date'] = datetime.datetime.now()`  for example, the expiry_date is changed too.
Can I create an exception for that? I want to use the expiry_date as a timeout for the session, but I have a JS code in the client which send requests every few minutes, thus always extend the session expiry_date.

I want a way (simple, I hope) to write to the session without extending this date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [session.set_expiry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry) function to set a custom expiry date, which will not be extended after modifying the session.

Comment: I guess I should use set_expiry(None)?

Comment: no, set_expiry(None) reverts back to the default behavior, which is to extend the date after each modification. You should update the expiration date manually by calling `set_expiry` only on requests that should extend the date.